# How do I authorise the update in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, plasma

In 14.04 there was a Muon updater program, which advised when system software updates were available and installed them after requesting the super user password. I have not been able to update since upgrading as the Muon program has been replaced by Plasma Discover, in which I cannot find a way to enter the password; so when I click the Update button a message says there is no authority. Either the programmer or (more likely) I have missed something obvious - what is it?

Comment: I am on a fresh install Kubuntu 16.04. I can update with `Discover`, it will ask me for the password. In `Dash > System` you should find an application named `Software Updater`, looks like `Muon` and works as well. One more possibility  is updating in terminal `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, mook765. The icon on the panel which I opened was just a notification warning of available updates. I was confused because these notifications came in a dialog box in 14.04. I found the necessary program as before in K>Applications>System as you said.